# Move single colored portion in an image to center of image using C# Aforge Library

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, aforge

[image: Orginal image with color on corner]

I want colored portion of image to be placed at center of bitmap image. I was not able to find Aforge filters which can achieve this. Can you please guide how to achieve this(there will be only one color loop every time, like attached image). I have used Aforge through out project, but if EmguCV (OpenCV) can achieve this, I am open to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this using Aforge library, will provide link, code and result picture below.
[Aforge documentation](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/blobs_processing.html)

```
// create filter
ExtractBiggestBlob filter = new ExtractBiggestBlob( );
// apply the filter
Bitmap biggestBlobsImage = filter.Apply( image );
```

[image: Result image]

Because I have only one blob, used filter which can output biggest blob. Now the colored portion occupies total image and it's center, becomes center of image.